# how to find the amount of individual numbers in a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

been looking for a way to count individual numbers in a csv file

they look like this

```
17795,15252,2212
```

and some are on individual lines like

```
17795,15252,2212

20223

18992,19991
```

any help would be appreciated

tried using csv import and len and sum but that returned the wrong number, since it should be 942 but instead returned 5328

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question, even if it doesn't work. What exactly do you want? The count of lines containing only a single number?

Comment: You failed to show the current code  and a reasonable input. What we need for a [mre]... We cannot efficiently help you  without a [mre].

Comment: Just to clarify, would something like `17795,15252` be counted as 2 numbers or 10?

Comment: Show your code attempt, a *small* input file and actual vs. desired output.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the CSV File: Open the file and read its contents line by line.
2. Split Each Line by Commas: For each line, use the split(',') method to separate the numbers.
3. Convert Strings to Integers: Convert each split string into an integer.
4. Count the Numbers: Maintain a count of these numbers.

You can try this:

```
file_path = 'path_to_your_file.csv'

count = 0

# Open the file and read line by line
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        numbers = line.strip().split(',')   # Splitting each line by comma and counting the numbers
        count += len(numbers)

print("Total count of numbers:", count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split to split a string into an array, at a specified character, this would. If done for every line that can be used to count the numbers.

```
    total_count = 0

with open('your_file.csv', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        numbers = line.strip().split(',')
        total_count += len(numbers)

print(total_count)
```

I don't think it's the best way, but it's a quick one that I found.
Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set`:

```py
import csv

individual_nums = set()

with open(myfile) as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        individual_nums.update([item.strip() for item in row])

print("Total Nums: ", len(individual_nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re`:

To get all numbers individually (ie: `"123,456"` returns `6`):

```
len(re.findall(r"\d", file.read()))
```

To get all numbers as they read (ie: `"123,456"` returns `2`):

```
len(re.findall(r"\d+", file.read()))
```

Assuming were only dealing with integers. Otherwise you would need to include the decimal in the pattern